# Dockerfile + CI for C build

Tags: c, integration-testing, dockerfile

I recently built a CI for my course project in C. I made 3 stages, to build docker image, compile my C sources and run the said project.

That said, i think i could've do way better [here](https://gitlab.com/artandor/cours-cpp/) but i don't really know how. I don't have a really big experience with CI, and even if that one works i would like to hear about what you think about it.

What i would like to improve is scalability, generality (there probably will be a need at some point to separate my dockerfiles per subproject (main-atoi is a subproject), ...

Source code here : [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/artandor/cours-cpp/)

**Docker file**

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install gcc g++ -y

ADD ./ /home

VOLUME /home/build /home/build
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
- build-image
- build
- run

before_script:
- docker info

build-image:
  stage: build-image
  tags:
  - build-docker
  script:
  - docker build -t artandor/debian9-cpp:v1-tp1 .

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - cours
  script:
  - docker run -v /home/build:/home/build --rm artandor/debian9-cpp:v1-tp1 gcc -Wall -Werror /home/main-atoi/myatoibase.c /home/main-atoi/main-atoi.c -o /home/build/main-test

run:
  stage: run
  dependencies:
  - build
  tags:
  - cours
  script:
  - docker run -v /home/build:/home/build --rm artandor/debian9-cpp:v1-tp1 /home/build/main-test
  - cp /home/build/main-test ./
  artifacts:
    name: "Main Atoi Binary - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
    - ./main-test
```

Comment: I added the code. Sorry for not respecting the guidelines, but it seemed to be a bit big to add it here. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that's fairly small for Code Review `:-)`.  Thanks for including the code; I hope you get good reviews (I'm not sufficiently skilled with Docker or Gitlab to answer it myself, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate project for your Dockfile and let gitlab keep the image in a [container repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html). That way you will not need to rebuild the image every build and you can reuse the container in other project without rebuilding it.